# TYPO3: Page Not Found if behind Frontend Login

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, felogin

I have a TYPO3 10.4 with Frontend Login enabled. Subpages are behind a FE Login:

[image: Structure]

If i want to link to an subpage domain.com/page1/page1-1/page1-1-1/
I get an 404 Error:

```
Page Not Found
The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: Subsection was found and not accessible
```

In my TypoScript I have:

```
config {
    typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages = 2450
    typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages_addParams = &return_url=###RETURN_URL###&pageId=###PAGE_ID###
}
```

According to [the documentation about typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#typolinklinkaccessrestrictedpages)

How can I setup my page to redirect to the login form with the right URL.

Comment: Hey Oliver, I've found a solution with the extension plan2net/sierrha. But since this feels like i workaround, I decided to add this as comment here. I didn't research further on it.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration is only used when you generate links. This does not handle cases which directly access the URL.
https://github.com/plan2net/sierrha can help you with that.